# Zoom Audio Device not displaying in Mac Audio/MIDI for use

Tags: macos, mac, audio, zoom, zoom.app

I'm a music teacher who is very interested in using Zoom and it's sound sharing ability.
Previously I had the Zoom Audio Driver (can't remember exactly what it's called) present in both my Audio/MIDI setup, but also available in my system as audio selections.

I did a reformat of my computer and reinstalled Zoom (have uninstalled and reinstalled several times), but no Zoom Audio Driver is present.

Is this something that needs to be installed separately? Where would I find it and I guess more importantly why did it not install in my system this time around? My understanding was that it is installed with the Zoom desktop app.

Current OS is Mac OS Ventura 13.3.1

Comment: The best I can garner is that it's installed 'when you need it'. See this article - https://www.techradar.com/how-to/improve-zoom-audio-with-zoomaudiodevice-and-pro-tools - & its link to - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_yiw9FFf71yliPLtluGO52Qz1qfrGIItf983j49UV-w/edit?fbclid=IwAR26-BN1R_NBcMZXS9JCXIjYchsyeDMkRzi-qNX5raH1xvi9EVkot-rcI5Y

Answer (score 2):

From the resources provided by Tetsujin, I can confirm that the resolution is that the audio driver is installed when you try to screen share with audio.

[Improve Zoom audio with ZoomAudioDevice and ProTools](https://www.techradar.com/how-to/improve-zoom-audio-with-zoomaudiodevice-and-pro-tools)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).